# Not able to type in Edittext with Asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, bluetooth

I'm working on an Android app that gets certain parameters trough a Bluetooth module.

I set up a service for this: I have a timer calling an AsyncTask to read these values and update my Listview UI if any values change. Everything seems to be working smoothly.

Some values are boolean and some are integers. I have Edittext boxes for the integers. If the user touches the Edittext I want to be able for the user to type a new value and when he presses the action button call a certain method to write this new value to my BT device.

So right now, when I touch the Edittext, the numeric keyboard pops up. No problem, but after a second it looses focus as the Asynctask is constantly updating all the Edittexts.

My question is, should I just stop my timed asynctask to be able to type and write the new value to my device and then start my timer again?

Or what would be the most efficient approach to be able to type in the Edittext and then call my method with this value as argument?

I'd appreciate any help. This is my first app, so I'm learning as I go...

```
public class RefreshListParams extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
```

{

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{
   //Create request, get my data, and update my objects (serC)
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String res)
{
    super.onPostExecute(res);

    do{
        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }while (serC.data == null);


    TextView textv;
    CheckedTextView check;
    ListViewItem edit;

    try {

        paramAdapter ad = (paramAdapter) pholder.listv.getAdapter();
        int x = 0;

        byte[] b = serR.data;

        for (int i =0; i<ad.objects.length; i++)
        {

            if (ad.getItemViewType(i) == paramAdapter.TYPE_CHECK)
            {
                textv = (TextView) pholder.view.findViewById(R.id.parameters);
                if (coilParam[i])
                    pholder.listv.setItemChecked(i, true);

                else
                    pholder.listv.setItemChecked(i, false);

            }
            else
            if (ad.getItemViewType(i) == paramAdapter.TYPE_VALUE)
            {
                edit = (ListViewItem) ad.getItem(i);

                                }
        }

        ad.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }catch (ClassCastException cce)
    {
        cce.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can't update the Ui in an another Thread than the Ui thread. But you can use `runOnUiThread(new Runnable());` with your activity. Or do the update in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Wouldnt i need to stop the asynctask for the cursor to appear and the user see what he's typing?

Comment: Can I see your `timer AsyncTask` ?

Comment: Edited my original question with the code...

Comment: Why do you have a `Thread.sleep(50)` ?

Comment: The device connected to my bluetooth module might take a little to respond, so i used that to wait for data to be available...